# Is there a way to run Windows apps on Ubuntu without Wine or Virtual Machines?

Tags: windows, wine

Is there any way to run Windows apps on Ubuntu without Wine or Virtual Machines, I tried to run some games with Wine. it don't work?

Comment: Not all Windows games will run properly using Wine. You can also use PlayOnLinux to run supported Windows games on Ubuntu. Otherwise dual-boot Windows with Ubuntu.

Comment: Which apps are we talking about?  Other than wine or wine related software or virtual machine with windows install I don't know of any other way to run a windows program on Linux.

Comment: Ubuntu is not a drop-in Windows replacement. They have very different histories and goals. Ubuntu does not run Windows .exe applications natively - some kind of additional compatibility layer is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have another machine that is running Windows, and your game is available on the Steam platform, and you also have a reasonably fast network connection to that machine, then you can consider using Steam's in-home streaming feature. Basically it is running the game/software on Windows, but streams the input/output to another machine that also has Steam installed. Since it is almost like video streaming, this requires a fast connection.

Although it is designed for Steam applications, this feature can work for non-Steam games as well if they can be registered into your [Steam library](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2219-YDJV-5557). However, note that some non-Steam games cannot work properly when they are managed/launched by Steam.

Reference: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/steam-in-home-streaming-play-windows-games-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

There's a commercial solution, [Crossover Office](https://www.codeweavers.com/), which is focused on major productivity apps. However, since they display the WINE logo, I suspect there's WINE under the hood.